# PHP - Get % of a sentence in whole words

Tags: php

So, I have this, but this fails when I am trying with a sentence with more than 6 words.

What I've done so far:

```
// My Sentence
$str = "Hello Stack Overflow";
// Split it into words with the delimiter being a space
$split = explode(" ", $str);
// Count Strings and divide it with number 3
$divider = str_word_count($str) / 3;

$last2 = $split[count($split)-$divider]; // penultimate word
$last1 = $split[count($split)-1]; // last word

// if $ divider gets penultimate word (don't more than that)
if ($divider < 2){
    echo $last2 . " " . $last1 . "<br>";} //echo last 2 words
else {
    echo $last2 . " " . $split[count($split)-2] . " " . $last1 . "<br>";} //echo last 3 words
```

It gets "Stack Overflow", so far so good.

What I am looking for is a way to get something like this:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you make another example? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @user1231958 watch a sentence like "Hello Stack Overflow" --> I want to echo that in 2 lines: **1)** HELLO STACK at the top (the longest space in screen) and **2)** OVERFLOR at the bottom (the smallest part of sentence).

Comment: This is a very specific use case. Where and when to split words to new lines depends on factors like grammar, tone and readability. If you're trying to prevent widows, I use something like `echo preg_replace('/\\s+([^\\s]+\\s*)$/','&nbsp;$1',$str)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = 'Hello Stack Overflow!';

$parts = explode(' ',preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$str));
$index = round(count($parts)*0.7);
$remaining = array_splice($parts,$index); // parts passed as reference &

echo 'FIRST LINE: '.implode(' ',$parts);
echo "\n";
echo 'LAST LINE: '.implode(' ',$remaining);

?>
```

Prints:

```
FIRST LINE: Hello Stack
LAST LINE: Overflow!
```

You're using explode correctly, but use array_splice to modify the original exploded array to chop off the last 30% (leaving 70%, hence the 0.7 multiplier). Then implode both parts to put them back together.

Honestly though, I'm not sure what use case there is for something like this question (and this solution). I'm betting this is an XY problem and the OP simply hasn't provided enough contextual information.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "Stack Overflow";
$len = floor(strlen($str)*0.3);
$substr1 = substr($str, 0, $len);
$substr2 = substr($str, $len-1);
echo "FIRST: ".$substr1;
echo "SECOND: ".$substr2;
```

This should do it.

Comment: This will give partial words. The OP is looking for ways to split _whole words_.

Comment: I think he wants to go by words (delimited by spaces) not length.

Comment: This is not what I was actually looking for... :)